# Not able to connect to MySQL instance installed as a Docker Container using JDBC or MySQL Workbench

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, docker, mysql-workbench

I'm a noobie to docker and just installed docker and managed to create a container for mysql instance.

docker run --name=mysql_container -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -p 6603:6603 mysql/mysql-server

Able to access the mysql instance using docker exec.

docker exec -it mysql_container mysql -uroot -p

Anyhow, not able to connect to the docker mysql instance with the mysql workbench (mysql service in the local machine is down). tried for the host localhost and 0.0.0.0 and still no luck.

I just run the command "docker inspect mysql_container" and the response is as follows:

```
[
{
    "Id": "12a30238bf11b08d9c029c528274db96175cc2edd976c8861e566e3ef4e26775",
    "Created": "2021-07-05T00:42:17.1792371Z",
    "Path": "/entrypoint.sh",
    "Args": [
        "mysqld"
    ],
    "State": {
        "Status": "running",
        "Running": true,
        "Paused": false,
        "Restarting": false,
        "OOMKilled": false,
        "Dead": false,
        "Pid": 1836,
        "ExitCode": 0,
        "Error": "",
        "StartedAt": "2021-07-05T00:42:17.567659Z",
        "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z",
        "Health": {
            "Status": "healthy",
            "FailingStreak": 0,
            "Log": [
                {
                    "Start": "2021-07-05T01:32:52.8156541Z",
                    "End": "2021-07-05T01:32:52.85896Z",
                    "ExitCode": 0,
                    "Output": "mysqld is alive\n"
                },
                {
                    "Start": "2021-07-05T01:33:22.8668644Z",
                    "End": "2021-07-05T01:33:22.9092576Z",
                    "ExitCode": 0,
                    "Output": "mysqld is alive\n"
                },
                {
                    "Start": "2021-07-05T01:33:52.9167436Z",
                    "End": "2021-07-05T01:33:52.9587054Z",
                    "ExitCode": 0,
                    "Output": "mysqld is alive\n"
                },
                {
                    "Start": "2021-07-05T01:34:22.9666096Z",
                    "End": "2021-07-05T01:34:23.0097958Z",
                    "ExitCode": 0,
                    "Output": "mysqld is alive\n"
                },
                {
                    "Start": "2021-07-05T01:34:53.0175935Z",
                    "End": "2021-07-05T01:34:53.0610566Z",
                    "ExitCode": 0,
                    "Output": "mysqld is alive\n"
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "Image": "sha256:1504607f1ce72dde82fc3377dce506b347594baf0698ddb0b493977e6f07d739",
    "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/12a30238bf11b08d9c029c528274db96175cc2edd976c8861e566e3ef4e26775/resolv.conf",
    "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/12a30238bf11b08d9c029c528274db96175cc2edd976c8861e566e3ef4e26775/hostname",
    "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/12a30238bf11b08d9c029c528274db96175cc2edd976c8861e566e3ef4e26775/hosts",
    "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/12a30238bf11b08d9c029c528274db96175cc2edd976c8861e566e3ef4e26775/12a30238bf11b08d9c029c528274db96175cc2edd976c8861e566e3ef4e26775-json.log",
    "Name": "/mysql_container",
    "RestartCount": 0,
    "Driver": "overlay2",
    "Platform": "linux",
    "MountLabel": "",
    "ProcessLabel": "",
    "AppArmorProfile": "",
    "ExecIDs": null,
    "HostConfig": {
        "Binds": null,
        "ContainerIDFile": "",
        "LogConfig": {
            "Type": "json-file",
            "Config": {}
        },
        "NetworkMode": "default",
        "PortBindings": {
            "6603/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "",
                    "HostPort": "6603"
                }
            ]
        },
        "RestartPolicy": {
            "Name": "no",
            "MaximumRetryCount": 0
        },
        "AutoRemove": false,
        "VolumeDriver": "",
        "VolumesFrom": null,
        "CapAdd": null,
        "CapDrop": null,
        "CgroupnsMode": "host",
        "Dns": [],
        "DnsOptions": [],
        "DnsSearch": [],
        "ExtraHosts": null,
        "GroupAdd": null,
        "IpcMode": "private",
        "Cgroup": "",
        "Links": null,
        "OomScoreAdj": 0,
        "PidMode": "",
        "Privileged": false,
        "PublishAllPorts": false,
        "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
        "SecurityOpt": null,
        "UTSMode": "",
        "UsernsMode": "",
        "ShmSize": 67108864,
        "Runtime": "runc",
        "ConsoleSize": [
            63,
            144
        ],
        "Isolation": "",
        "CpuShares": 0,
        "Memory": 0,
        "NanoCpus": 0,
        "CgroupParent": "",
        "BlkioWeight": 0,
        "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
        "BlkioDeviceReadBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": null,
        "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": null,
        "CpuPeriod": 0,
        "CpuQuota": 0,
        "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
        "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
        "CpusetCpus": "",
        "CpusetMems": "",
        "Devices": [],
        "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
        "DeviceRequests": null,
        "KernelMemory": 0,
        "KernelMemoryTCP": 0,
        "MemoryReservation": 0,
        "MemorySwap": 0,
        "MemorySwappiness": null,
        "OomKillDisable": false,
        "PidsLimit": null,
        "Ulimits": null,
        "CpuCount": 0,
        "CpuPercent": 0,
        "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
        "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
        "MaskedPaths": [
            "/proc/asound",
            "/proc/acpi",
            "/proc/kcore",
            "/proc/keys",
            "/proc/latency_stats",
            "/proc/timer_list",
            "/proc/timer_stats",
            "/proc/sched_debug",
            "/proc/scsi",
            "/sys/firmware"
        ],
        "ReadonlyPaths": [
            "/proc/bus",
            "/proc/fs",
            "/proc/irq",
            "/proc/sys",
            "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
        ]
    },
    "GraphDriver": {
        "Data": {
            "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/03a28621f28b92827eaf38f097b25ba53ab31091c3554e0600b721e09c9beb1f-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f43a2ac50d2b3b388b1947fa3a44859c932394c977df5d06e8947eabb13fe154/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/f4fbbff8a89d0bd37b24fcdc05c87bb8d5b322a2cfb756a8bc776c22bef0ba0f/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/47159eeeb0fbd80023fd2ca0e4137766720705180a51fe91dc451fb633cb53ab/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/a7417372516cb1940f18eee241a818b1848e5ff42742fbd77d4df90fd6bd0bcf/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/da77a65d253059537efe311f21e4ce98f70aca276e3e0ecf57757951d77ce0f3/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/8f2a3f629a3bf570743b74f0d9a4211f0666bec21236d4dbd3aa4f6bdbd70743/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/83115d68cd30bf8f45d038c01136c983d94e4d1499ec05a720c2c63aaa0a82a8/diff",
            "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/03a28621f28b92827eaf38f097b25ba53ab31091c3554e0600b721e09c9beb1f/merged",
            "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/03a28621f28b92827eaf38f097b25ba53ab31091c3554e0600b721e09c9beb1f/diff",
            "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/03a28621f28b92827eaf38f097b25ba53ab31091c3554e0600b721e09c9beb1f/work"
        },
        "Name": "overlay2"
    },
    "Mounts": [],
    "Config": {
        "Hostname": "12a30238bf11",
        "Domainname": "",
        "User": "",
        "AttachStdin": false,
        "AttachStdout": false,
        "AttachStderr": false,
        "ExposedPorts": {
            "3306/tcp": {},
            "33060/tcp": {},
            "33061/tcp": {},
            "6603/tcp": {}
        },
        "Tty": false,
        "OpenStdin": false,
        "StdinOnce": false,
        "Env": [
            "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root",
            "MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=%",
            "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin",
            "MYSQL_UNIX_PORT=/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock"
        ],
        "Cmd": [
            "mysqld"
        ],
        "Healthcheck": {
            "Test": [
                "CMD-SHELL",
                "/healthcheck.sh"
            ]
        },
        "Image": "mysql/mysql-server",
        "Volumes": null,
        "WorkingDir": "",
        "Entrypoint": [
            "/entrypoint.sh"
        ],
        "OnBuild": null,
        "Labels": {}
    },
    "NetworkSettings": {
        "Bridge": "",
        "SandboxID": "7c248259a881c317cc21697199a87a7f4706c4a07f0f91c39632194318eab418",
        "HairpinMode": false,
        "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
        "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "Ports": {
            "3306/tcp": null,
            "33060/tcp": null,
            "33061/tcp": null,
            "6603/tcp": [
                {
                    "HostIp": "0.0.0.0",
                    "HostPort": "6603"
                },
                {
                    "HostIp": "::",
                    "HostPort": "6603"
                }
            ]
        },
        "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/7c248259a881",
        "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
        "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
        "EndpointID": "f6ac3760c826e052b525292499ee166608f8307f4cd8618022bfdd8600cdfa54",
        "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
        "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
        "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
        "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
        "IPPrefixLen": 16,
        "IPv6Gateway": "",
        "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
        "Networks": {
            "bridge": {
                "IPAMConfig": null,
                "Links": null,
                "Aliases": null,
                "NetworkID": "15d5f77b059c4a53a1182f61dd8cf54734e63e79058cd12d04a2e54867302a37",
                "EndpointID": "f6ac3760c826e052b525292499ee166608f8307f4cd8618022bfdd8600cdfa54",
                "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                "IPv6Gateway": "",
                "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                "DriverOpts": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

]

The application.properties of the spring boot application was like

```
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:6603/test
#spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://0.0.0.0:6603/test
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://172.17.0.2:6603/test
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

Comment: Also uninstalled firewall to ensure the ports or ips are not blocked.

Comment: what is the output of ifconfig for wlan/docker0/ or similar adapter, in that inet is the value you should be checking

Comment: hello @silentsudo, the docker inspect command gives back the default network information also, hope that could help.

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something. But you seem to be sharing port 6603 while the database is running on tcp/3306.

Comment: thanks @pat, i did check "netstat -an" and there was no such port 3306(default port) running but specifically 6603 was listening with tcp protocol.